# Defining a Symfony command as a service causes preg_match() exception

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

I have the following command, which successfully prints styled messages to the bash terminal when called:

```
class DoSomethingCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('do:something')
            ->setDescription('Does a thing');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);

        $io->title('About to do something ... ');

        $io->success('Done doing something.');
    }
}
```

... but when I add the following in services.yml in order to try to define my command as a service ...

```
services:
  console_command.do_something:
    class: AppBundle\Command\DoSomethingCommand
    arguments:
      - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
    tags:
      - { name: console.command }
```

... I get this error:

> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
>   in
>   src/app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:665

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you inject the service but your do any constructor function in your command.

That means you are currently injecting the `EntityManager` (object) into the parameter of the Command class (which need a `string` or `null` , that's why you have your error)

```
# Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command
class Command
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
```

Then, as defined in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html) you must call the parent constructor

```
class YourCommand extends Command
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;

        // you *must* call the parent constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

**ContainerAwareCommand**

Note than your class can extends `ContainerAwareCommand` and you will be able to access public services via `$this->getContainer()->get('SERVICE_ID')`.
This isn't a bad practice as a command can be seen as a controller. (And usually your controllers have the container injected)

Comment: Thanks -- that did the trick. I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to.